# What is wrong with my orchid? Tips of leaves are turning brown and soft

Tags: leaves, orchids

I have a relatively young Miltoniopsis orchid that is suffering from browning on the leaves. This had happened previously, it went away, and is now happening again. In the first picture you can see the middle right and the most center leaves have the most recent browning. The leaves turned translucent and are very soft to the touch. The bottom right and top right show leaves that this happened to before but then it stopped and they just sort of dried up so those leaf tips are "crispy." The second picture just shows one of the soft brown leaf tips more clearly.

It hasn't bloomed yet since I've had it (about a year and a half), although it did try sending up a spike but the spike died before any blooms. It is potted in orchid medium from repotme.com and is in a slotted pot. It has healthy looking green roots. I water it about once a week with a good soak and fertilize weakly, every other watering typically. I did try spraying the leaves with hydrogen peroxide and no fizzing occurred (like I have seen before when repotting and cleaning up any old roots).

Can anyone tell me what is wrong? Is this a fungus or bacteria? Should I remove these parts of the leaves or the entire brown leaves or let them fall off on their own?

[image: picture of orchid with browning leaf tips, showing all leaves]

[image: picture of orchid with browning leaf tips, showing one particularly soft, brown leaf more clearly]
[image: picture of orchid roots in bark. bark is wet from recent watering and roots are small and green]